# Can not find business object factory with extensionID

Tags: intershop

I'm working on **Business Object layer** in Intershop 7 and trying to create custom **business object** A1PromotionBO with related **business repository (extension)**.

I've already done Persistent Object layer (A1PromotionPO, Mgrs, EDL model, auto-generated classes, database..).

By following this Cookbook - Business Objects (https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/27K270), i've

created package *.a1promotion.capi that contains:

```
 - interface A1PromotionBO extends BusinessObject
 - interface A1PromotionBORepository extends BusinessObjectRepository
 - interface A1PromotionBORepositoryExtension extends BusinessObjectExtension<RepositoryBO>, A1PromotionBORepository
```

created package *.a1promotion.internal that contains:

```
 - class ORMA1PromotionBOImpl extends AbstractExtensibleObjectBO<A1PromotionPO> implements A1PromotionBO
 - class ORMA1PromotionBORepositoryImpl extends AbstractDomainRepositoryBOExtension implements A1PromotionBORepository, ObjectMapper<Object, A1PromotionBO>
 - class A1PromotionBORepositoryExtensionFactory extends AbstractDomainRepositoryBOExtensionFactory
```

**EXTENSION_ID** = "A1PromotionBORepository" is defined both in interface A1PromotionBORepositoryExtension and class A1PromotionBORepositoryExtensionFactory.

---

And now pipelet that returns collection of A1PromotionBO fails on line when creating A1PromotionBORepository promotionBORepository:

```
public class GetPromotions extends Pipelet {
    @Inject
    private CurrentApplicationBOProvider applicationBOProvider;

    /** The domain mgr. */
    @Inject
    private DomainMgr domainMgr;

    @Override
    public int execute(PipelineDictionary dict) throws PipeletExecutionException {
        final ApplicationBO applicationBO = applicationBOProvider.get();
        final A1PromotionBORepository promotionBORepository = applicationBO.getRepository(A1PromotionBORepositoryExtensionFactory.EXTENSION_ID);

        final String promotionDomainName = dict.get("PromotionDomain");
        final Domain promotionDomain = domainMgr.getDomainByName(promotionDomainName);
        if (null == promotionDomain) {
            throw new PipeletExecutionException("Mandatory input parameter 'ProductsDomain' not available in pipeline dictionary.");
        }

        final Collection<A1PromotionBO> promotions = (Collection<A1PromotionBO>)promotionBORepository.getAllPromotions();
        dict.put("Promotions", promotions);

        return PIPELET_NEXT;
    }
}
```

Full stack track of exception :

```
Caused by: com.intershop.component.application.capi.ApplicationBOException: Can not find business object factory with extensionID A1PromotionBORepository in application ApplicationBO(Shop@A1-Site (app=a1Shop.Backoffice))
    at com.intershop.component.application.internal.ApplicationBORepositoriesExtensionImpl.getRepository(ApplicationBORepositoriesExtensionImpl.java:49)
    at com.intershop.component.application.internal.ApplicationBOImpl.getRepository(ApplicationBOImpl.java:222)
    at hr.a1.bo.promotion.pipelet.GetPromotions.execute(GetPromotions.java:44)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipeletNode.executeNode(PipeletNode.java:346)
    ... 42 more
```

Comment: Did you configure your Repository extension with the component framework? I see that in that cookbook it isn't very clear that u need to do that..

Comment: Also make sure that your application type `a1Shop.Backoffice` mentions the cartridge that contains your mentioned code artifacts (BO, BO Repository, PO, component and so on).

Comment: Both answers helped a lot, i did miss component definitions and the respective cartridge had to be added to cartridge list of application type a1Shop.Backoffice.